# SSL Certificate not trusted on initial connection

Tags: android, ssl, trustmanager

I have a really frustrating SSL bug where, depending on connection order, a valid certificate is not being trusted.

So if on startup, I connect directly to server A. the trust manager will fail to verify the chain with the error: 
`java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

But if instead I connect to server B, and then subsequently to server A it will trust the same certificate it previously claimed was invalid.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be happening to cause this flip flop in trust?

This is how I'm setting up the trust manager:

```
    try {

      TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
      tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
      X509TrustManager manager = (X509TrustManager)tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
      manager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
      Log.d("Auth","Did trust it");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("Auth","Didn't trust it", e);
    }
```

As far as I can tell everything that happens up to the handshake is identical between the different connections. The only difference is the address. This is happening while running on android 10 on a pixel 3.

Comment: Make sure that all intermediate certificates are served by both sites. I  could imagine that site A and B use the same intermediate certificates but only site B sends all the certificates. If you first visit B the intermediate certificate might be cached and thus could be used to validate the cert of A. But if you first visit A it will fail validation due to missing intermediate certificates.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks! I hadn't thought of that but will check that out immediately.